# Restrict package purchasing while being already subscribed

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site for selling and buying items. I have packages that a user can subscribe to. Iam using Onsups theme (addforest packages). I have a free package which he get to post some ads and it has also time limit. My problem is that if the user bought a package lets say the free one, and then he tried to re buy it, it will extends its time limit again and add them to the old one. I want to disable the ability to buy a new package while your old package is valied. Is there any suggestions?